# Installing SSRS to use for Postgresql Database (adempiere)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, postgresql-9.1, adempiere

I'm currently using Postgresql Database 9.1 (running Adempiere)

I've been using SQL Server Data Tools on my computer and connecting directly to the server computer to create reports.

Now i want to install the Reporting Services aspect on the computer server so that other users can access the reports through the Report Manager. And also so that it can automatically deliver reports to the users

Is it possible to install SQL Server 2008 in the same computer as Postgresql? And if so, what are the steps that i need to take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible to install.

and You should not run into any problems, both servers run on different ports (by default) so both should run happily side by side.

But I dont think its supported, so you won't find any instructions.

Hope it helps.